# Confusion with C ~ operator (bitwise Not) and comparing char variables

Tags: c, byte, bit-manipulation

Using "ordinary C", I wish to compare two 8 bit bytes to determine if the second is the bitwise complement of the first.  For example if Byte1 is binary 00001111 (15 in decimal) I want to test whether or not Byte2 is binary 11110000 (240 in decimal).  I expected to do this using unsigned chars to represent the bytes, the C bitwise NOT operator "~" and a simple if( == ) test.

Can anyone explain for me why the following code doesn't work (ie. I expect it to output "True" but it actually outputs "False").

```
unsigned char X = 15;
unsigned char Y = 240;  

if( Y == ~X)
    printf("True");
else
    printf("False");
```

I guess I could XOR the bytes together then test for 255, but why doesn't the above if( == ) comparison work ?

Thanks,

Martin.

Comment: (Whoops, looks like I added my comments (Further questions) in the wrong place...) @Jens      Thanks Ben and Jens and others. I am sure what you say is the cause of my difficulty. But just to make sure I understand...

Comment: Lets say its a 16 bit system. So 15 decimal gets promoted to 00000000 00001111 binary, then gets complemented to 11111111 11110000 binary. Then this is to be compared to 240 decimal, which I guess gets promoted to 16 bits too, to facilitate the comparison, so we end up comparing 11111111 11110000 and 00000000 11110000, which obviously aren't equal. Ok, that makes sense. @Ben

Comment: I have noticed if I declare the "bytes" as "signed char"s, the comparison works. Does this mean when the 240 gets promoted to 16 bits, it's actually interpreted as -16 (two's complement), so when it gets promoted to 16 bits it gets sign extended to 11111111 11110000 and so it does compare as equal to ~15. Is this what's going on ? So pehaps using signed chars is a good / valid solution ? What do you think ? Thank you for your assistance, Martin.

Answer (score 10):

Because *integral promotion* causes the math on the right side to be done as `int`.  If you assigned the result back to a `char` like `unsigned char Z = ~X` those upper bits would be truncated off again and `Y == Z`.

Comment: …or use a cast `(z == (char)~x)`

Comment: @sidyll: you'd need to cast to `unsigned char` -- `char` might get sign extended

Comment: @ChrisDodd Sure, sorry about that.

Comment: You can also explicitly truncate those bits with `& 0xFF`.

Answer (score 5):

The ~ operator causes its operands to be promoted to int before being complemented. ~15 is not 240 but some other value, depending on the size of int.

Just use `if (X + Y == 255)` and it should work.

Comment: Since the concern here is bits, I think `if ((X ^ Y) == 255)` may be more instructive here.

Comment: Thanks Ben and Jens and others.  I am sure what you say is the cause of my difficulty.  But just to make sure I understand...

Comment: Lets say its a 16 bit system.  So 15 decimal gets promoted to 00000000 00001111 binary, then gets complemented to 11111111 11110000 binary.  Then this is to be compared to 240 decimal, which I guess gets promoted to 16 bits too, to facilitate the comparison, so we end up comparing 11111111 11110000 and 00000000 11110000, which obviously aren't equal.  Ok, that makes sense.

Comment: I have noticed if I declare the "bytes" as "signed char"s, the comparison works.  Does this mean when the 240 gets promoted to 16 bits, it's actually interpreted as -16 (two's complement), so when it gets promoted to 16 bits it gets sign extended to 11111111 11110000 and so it does compare as equal to ~15.  Is this what's going on ?  So pehaps using signed chars is a good / valid solution ?  What do you think ?  Thank you for your assistance, Martin.

Comment: Yes. Promotion is value-respecting, so a byte 0xF0, interpreted as a signed char has value -16 and the promotion sign-extends it. For testing bitwise complement, using signed char is a valid solution, because if the two are bitwise complements of each other, exactly one of them is negative.

Comment: You might want to use `X ^ Y == 255` - although using `+` works too, `^` makes it clearer that you're interested in the bitwise representation.

Comment: Martin, you got it. But I recommend to avoid both casting and avoid using signed types when operating on bit representations. Understand what integer promotions are, when they happen, and that unsigned types cannot overflow (unsigned arithmetic is always modulo 2^n where n is the size in bits of the type).