# Bitwise negation of unsigned char

Tags: c, c99, integer-promotion

This is a question relating the c99 standard and concerns integer promotions and bitwise negations of unsigned char.

In section 6.5.3.3 it states that:

> The integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result
>   has the promoted type. If the promoted type is an unsigned type, the
>   expression ~E is equivalent to the maximum value representable in that
>   type minus E.

Am I understanding that correctly when I say that, that means that:

```
unsigned int ui = ~ (unsigned char) ~0; // ui is now 0xFF00.
```

My confusion stems from a discussion with a collegue where he is seeing the following behaviour in our compiler.

```
unsigned char uc = 0;
unsigned char ucInverted = ~0;

if( ~uc == ~0 )              // True, obviously
if( ~ucInverted == ~(~0) )   // False as it evaluates to: 0xFF00 == 0x0000
if( ~uc == ucInverted )      // False as it evaluates to: 0xFFFF == 0x00FF
if( uc == ~ucInverted )      // False as it evaluates to: 0x0000 == 0xFF00
```

This behaviour is confirmed with gcc.

Is it possible to get proper expected char comparisons where each of these cases will evaluate to true?

Comment: Read [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796041/calculating-ranges-of-data-types-in-c/17796122#17796122) If `~0` is a trap representation, then the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: These are unsigned, the trap representation in this case is irrelevant. see also footnote 53 in 6.2.6.2 linked from the linked answer.

Comment: @Hasturkun: `~0` is not unsigned...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: True. As far as I understand though, still not an issue as there's wording stating that "no arithmetic operation on valid values can generate a trap representation other than as part of an exceptional condition such as an overflow." for signed types as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusion with C ~ operator (bitwise Not) and comparing char variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940815/confusion-with-c-operator-bitwise-not-and-comparing-char-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~uc` is of type `int` (value `0xFFFF`).  `ucInverted` is of type `unsigned char` (value `0xFF`), which is then promoted to `int` (value `0x00FF`).  Thus they are not equal.

I guess you could do `if ((unsigned char)~uc == ucInverted)`.  Both operands will still undergo promotion, but they will have identical values before the promotion.

Comment: It just seems completely illogical to me that you must cast an unsigned char back to unsigned char in order to properly compare it to an unsigned char. Or is that just me?

Comment: @Kenneth: Once one accepts that `~` causes type promotion, the rest is entirely logical ;)

Comment: `~uc` is likely of type `signed int`.

Comment: No, really promotions will be done (on almost all architectures) to `signed int`, and never to `unsigned int`. And then, also, this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Yes, you're right, integer promotions favour `signed` wherever possible.  Answer updated.  (Although I'm not sure what you mean by "not an answer to the question"?)

Comment: I suppose that just because I don't like it doesn't make it less true :)